# Regex replace unterminated parenthetical

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all unnecessary breaks in a string. I have written a Regex replace but it throws an error: SyntaxError: unterminated parenthetical

```js
var str = "<H1>sdflk</H1><BR><BR><BR><BR><P>test</P><BR><BR><BR><BR>";
str.replace(/((</[a-zA-Z0-9]+>)(<BR>)+)/,"\$2");
```

But I don't see the missing parenthese.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please refrain from parsing HTML with RegEx as it will [drive you insane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use an [HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) instead.

Comment: I edited the question. I used $1 instead of $2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add `\` before `/` in the re:

```
/((<\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+>)(<BR>)+)/
```

Another option is to use `RegExp`:

```
re = new RegExp("((</[a-zA-Z0-9]+>)(<BR>)+)");
"<H1>sdflk</H1><BR><BR><BR><BR><P>test</P><BR><BR><BR><BR>".replace(re,"\$1");
```

Comment: Try also `[/]` instead of `\/`

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I now have the problem that is only replaces the first occurrence in the string.

Comment: The regex doesn't work (even with global and case ignore flags) but good job on the accept

Comment: @WillemdeWit: Just use `new RegExp("((</[a-zA-Z0-9]+>)(<BR>)+)", "g")`. (I added `"g"`)

Comment: @Esailija: what do you mean "the regex doesn't work"? The regex works.

Comment: `"<H1>sdflk</H1><BR><BR><BR><BR><P>test</P><BR><BR><BR><BR>".replace(/((<\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+>)(<BR>)+)/gi,"\$1");
//"<H1>sdflk</H1><BR><BR><BR><BR><P>test</P><BR><BR><BR><BR>"`

Comment: @Esailija: but that is not the same! you will remove br's even when there not closing tags before them!

Comment: @IgorChubin I don't see that requirement anywhere. I would consider 500 brs without a closing tag before the first one unnecessary

Comment: @Esailija: I just explained where is there an error with `missing parenthesis`. I didn't fix the re itself. But I can do it also: just try `\$2` instead of `\$1`

Comment: @Esailija: you should use $2 instead of $1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z2C86/ I am using `\$2` there with `"g"` and `"i"` even. Yes I suppose the syntax error is fixed.

Comment: The working regex is: `"<H1>sdflk</H1><BR><BR><BR><BR><P>test</P><BR><BR><BR><BR>".replace(/((<\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+>)(<BR>)+)/g,'$2');`